# Error: Unknown provider - Karma, requirejs, angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, karma-runner

I get this error when i try to make a test

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $translateProvider <- $translate
```

I'm using karma with requirejs.

```
loadingCtrlSpec.js

    define([
    'angular',
    'angular-mocks',
    'app',
    'angular-translate'
    ], function(angular, mocks, app) {
        'use strict';

        describe('loadingCtrl', function(){
            var ctrl, scope, translate;
            beforeEach(mocks.module('TestApp'));

            beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
                scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
                translate = $injector.get('$translate');  

            }));                  

            it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
                expect(true).toBe(true);
            });

        });  
});
```

loadingCtrl.js

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('TestApp', [])
    .controller('loadingCtrl', ['$scope', '$translate', function($scope, $translate) {
        $translate(['build.DEFAULT_EMAIL_SUBJECT','build.DEFAULT_EMAIL_NOTES']).then(function (translations) {
            $scope.title = translations["build.DEFAULT_EMAIL_SUBJECT"];
            $scope.notes = translations["build.DEFAULT_EMAIL_NOTES"];
        });
    }]); })
```

If i don't use angular-translate ($translate) everything is working so i don't think the problem is from karma.conf.js or test-main.js (require.conf for karma).

Comment: This error indicate that angular can't find the $translate module. Check your karma.conf to see if the angular-translate file is correctly included

Answer (score 2):

Your `TestApp` module will need to specify the `pascalprecht.translate` module as a dependency. Also be sure to include `angular-translate` as a dependency when defining your main module so the relevant script gets loaded:

```js
define(['angular', 'angular-translate'], function (angular) {
    angular.module('TestApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);
});
```

Comment: The problem is not in the loadingCtrl.js, the module is working. When i run 'karma start' so the problem i think is in loadingCtrlSpec.js

Comment: To be able to use the `$translate` service anywhere in either `loadingCtrlSpec.js` or `loadingCtrl.js`, a dependency on the `pascalprecht.translate` module must be getting specified *somewhere*. I can't see how the `loadingCtrl` controller could get instantiated and have `$translate` injected without something more than what you've shown. There is no dependency on this module (or definition of the `$translate` service) shown in the code you've given; if you have that somewhere else, can you update the question to show that code?

Comment: not very standard naming, dear precht, for a module placed in the "angular-translate" package.